# Limit allowed operations to only NSDragOperationCopy

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop

I have a custom view that is a drag source. I want to limit the allowed drag operations to only a copy, and hence I return NSDragOperationCopy in my draggingSession:sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext: method.

For some reason this has no effect.

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with my code as returning NSDragOperationNone works as expected and blocks drags.

Below is the code from my NSView that is the dragging source. Dragging from the view to the "Trash" you'll see a NSDragOperationMove or NSDragOperationDelete even though I only want to allow the NSDragOperationCopy operation.

I've also uploaded a small demo project to demonstrate what I'm talking about: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/368222/test.zip.

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSString *imagePath = [path stringByAppendingString:@"/image.png"];

    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

    NSArray *file = [NSArray arrayWithObject:imagePath];
    NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard];
    [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSFilenamesPboardType] owner:nil];
    [pboard setPropertyList:file forType:NSFilenamesPboardType];

    [self dragImage:image at:NSZeroPoint offset:NSMakeSize(0, 0) event:event pasteboard:pboard source:self slideBack:NO];
}

- (NSDragOperation)draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session sourceOperationMaskForDraggingContext:(NSDraggingContext)context {
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}

- (void)draggingSession:(NSDraggingSession *)session endedAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint operation:(NSDragOperation)operation {
    NSLog(@"Dragging session ended with operation: %li", operation);
}
```

Anyone?

Thx!

Comment: Would you explain the last part of this – "returning NSDragOperationNone works as expected and block drags" – and post some code?

Comment: Hey noa. Updated the question with a small demo project.

Comment: Would you post the code here that you think might be relevant to your problem?

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. If not the trash can, etc., what is your desired and expected drag target?

Comment: It's not the target that's relevant. It's the allowed drag operations I'm focusing on. From the Apple's documentation: "Only one of the NSDraggingSource methods needs to be implemented: draggingSourceOperationMaskForLocal:. This method declares what types of operations the source allows to be performed." If I set this to only allow copies I would expect a drop on the trash to do nothing. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSDraggingSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html